# not able to access the "length" attribute of an array

Tags: java

I made a Manager class which inherits from an employee class...
I am facing problems while i am trying to access the length attribute of the array "managedEmployee" of the type "Employee"(Parent class)..

Could anybody tell me the reason for me not being able to access the length attribute of the nanagedEpployee array ????????
Thanks..

```
public class Manager extends Employee {

   int index = 0;
   private Employee[] managedEmployee = new Employee[10];

   public void inputManagedEmployee(Employee e) {

      if (e == null) {

         System.out.println("invalid Employee");

      } else {
         for (int x = 0; x < managedEmployee.length; x++) {

            managedEmployee[index] = e;
            index++;
         }

      }
   }

   public void displayManagerInfo() {

      System.out.println("The name of the  candidate is :" + getName());
      System.out.println("The Id of the candidate is:" + getID());
      System.out.println("The level of the candidate is :" + getLevel());
      System.out.println("the Title of the candidate is :" + getTitle());

      for (int x = 0; x <= index; x++) {
         if (managedEmployee[x] != null) {
            System.out.println("The name of the managed candidate is :"
                  + managedEmployee[x].getName());

         }
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`managedEmployee.lenght` is misspelled. Should be `managedEmployee.length`

I'm also guessing that inside your `for` loop, where it says `managedEmployee[index]=e;` that is should be `managedEmployee[x]=e;`